# Unable to get the expected html element details using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website using Python. I have been able to scrape it successfully, however the expected resulted is not fetching  up. I  think there is something to do with the JavaScript of  the web page.

My Code below:

```
driver.get(
        "https://my website")

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
all_text = soup.text
ct = all_text.replace('\n', ' ')
cl_text = ct.replace('\t', ' ')
cln_text_t = cl_text.replace('\r', ' ')
cln_text = re.sub(' +', ' ', cln_text_t)
print(cln_text)
```

Instead of giving me the website details it is giving the below data. Any idea how could I fix this?

```
html, body {height:100%;margin:0;} You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.........
```

Comment: can you share your url or html your are trying and mentioned your expected output as well

Comment: have you tried expected conditions to wait for your element to be present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need this `BeautifulSoup` at all? It doesn't seem to support JavaScript.

If you need to get web page text you can fetch the [document root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) using simple [XPath selector](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) of `//html` and get [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property of the resulting [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement)

Suggested code change:

```
driver.get(
        "my website")

root = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html")

all_text = root.get_attribute("innerText")
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. This worked. A good deal of learning as well for me today. :)